# SEO for imaged typography

Tags: html, seo

Since font rendering is a nightmare on cross platforms (i.e. windows has very ugly anti aliasing, and TTF fonts are not anti aliased at all) I came up with the idea to create a png file for every heading in my design.

My question however implies that if I would create a H1 html element and hide it with CSS while the title is shown by a png image, would search engines this work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are proposing is a very common method for replacing text with an image.  Search engines don't mind.

I would suggest that instead of hiding the element, move it off-screen, `-5000px` or so.  Also, your users are probably going to hate you, since your site will be slow.  Best just to deal with the typography as it is.  I don't know what Windows system you're using, but anti-aliasing works just fine on all of my Windows boxes.  If you need a different font, consider web fonts.